# VSCode Open Webview in secondary sidebar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am making an extension and I have two webviews.
I can move one of them to secondary sidebar by mouse, but how to do it using code?

Found some commands to interact with secondary sidebar, they call it auxiliary for some reason :

```
workbench.action.toggleAuxiliaryBar
workbench.action.focusAuxiliaryBar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can move it entirely programmatically - that is, without any user interaction at all.  The closest it seems you can get is this:

```js
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('<yourWebviewIdHere>.focus');

await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.moveFocusedView');
```

which would first focus your webview and then open a dialog asking the user where to move it.  `New secondary side bar entry` is one of the top choices.

In your ExtensionHost when debugging the extension, you can see a command like `<yourWebviewIdHere>.focus` in the Keyboard Shortcuts editor - search for the View `id` of your webView in the Keyboard Shortcuts.

The above requires you to first focus your webview but there is also the command `workbench.action.moveView` which when triggered will first ask the user which view to move and then ask where to move it.